# Display AngularJS inputs from the frontend

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I'm currently working on an AngularJS project where user inputs from a drop down list and a text box on a page can be displayed on a new page. For instance, selecting option of Mr and entering a name which is then displayed on a new page as "You're Mr YourName." How can this be done? Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select ng-model="title">
   <option>Mr</option>
   <option>Ms</option>
</select>
<input type="text" ng-model="yourName">
You're {{title}} {{yourName}}
```

Comment: I want the You're {{title}} {{yourName}} displayed on a new webpage. Any help?

Comment: I don't want it to be the homepage of my project. I want it to be displayed on another webpage.

Comment: @BorcheIvanov, I added a comment yesterday I guess you didn't see it.

Comment: @Sa E, please, see the comment I added yesterday.